# How does Gaussian Basis Function for regression handle a vector of X

Tags: regression, logistic, normal-distribution, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to understand the concept of Gaussian Basis Functions on regression models. From the equation:

$h_w(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} w_k \phi_k(x) = w^Tx$

where $\phi(x)$ is a Gaussian Basis function $\phi_j(x) = exp \{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2s^2}\}$

Say my input is a vector **X**, with 10 features, and I want to implement 5 Gaussian Basis functions over the data, thus $K=5$. So as per my understanding, the feature space will get *reduced* from 10 to 5. But, while implementation I am facing a doubt: does the basis function takes as input $x_i$ or a vector $x$? If it takes $x_i$, then while transformation the function will be applied over *all* the features, thus resulting in an expansion of feature space (10 x 5). If it takes the vector $x$, how shall it compute? does $(x-\mu)^2$ becomes $\sum(x_i - \mu)^2$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will be the whole vector $x$.  And generally you will want a weight matrix (e.g. covariance matrix) in the exponent to scale the features: $$\phi_j(x) = \exp\left(- (x-\mu_j)^T\Sigma_j(x-\mu_j) \right) $$ Note that the argument to the exponent is now a vector-matrix-vector product.

Comment: let me clarify : $(x-\mu_j)^T$ is a 1xn vector (where $n$ is the number of features). but why the summation is over $j$ ? for each basis function $\phi_j$ we are given a $\mu_j$ and $s$ right? i got confused in this part...

Comment: $\Sigma_j$ is not a summation, it is a positive semidefinite matrix. If you do  not want to re-scale the relative size of the input just choose $\Sigma_j = \frac{1}{s^2} I_{n\times n}$, where $I_{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: understood. can you give me a small example of this transformation such that i can understand intuitively what is happening?

Comment: thanks! related question though, why do we use Gaussian Basis functions to transform the input? to reduce complexity? how does it help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52546/discussion-between-stefan-jorgensen-and-koustuv-sinha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the vector $x$. You can also incorporate a weight matrix to re-scale your input data if this hasn't already been done in a pre-processing step. So the $j$th basis function would be
$$ \phi_j(x) = \exp\left( -(x-\mu_j)^T \Sigma_j(x-\mu_j) \right),$$
where $\Sigma_j = \frac{1}{s_j^2}I_n$ if you don't do any re-scaling ($I_n$ is the $n$x$n$ identity matrix).